# C2227: left of '->send' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, vector

I wrote a socket client server, and I create a socket vector list in mythread.h file but it gives me these errors that I can't fix:

**Code:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < v_->size(); i++) 
{
    if(((MYThread *)(v_)[i])->user_id_ != user_id_) 
    {
        ((MYThread *)(v_)[i])->send(strArray);
    }
}
```

**Errors:**

> D:\My_Socket\My_Socket\server\server\mythread.cpp:101: error: C2440: 'type > cast': cannot convert from 'std::vector>' to > 'MYThread *'
>       with
>       [
>       _Ty=MYThread *
>       ]
>
> D:\My_Socket\My_Socket\server\server\mythread.cpp:101: error: C2227: left of '->user_id_' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

mythrad.h file

```
#ifndef MYTHREAD_H
#define MYTHREAD_H

#include <QListWidget>
#include <QObject>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QAbstractSocket>
#include <QDebug>
#include <vector>
#include <QThread>
#include <QString>
#include <QPixmap>

class MYThread : public QThread
{
public:
explicit MYThread(QThread *parent = 0);
explicit MYThread(QTcpSocket *socket, QListWidget *list, std::vector<MYThread *> *v, int user_id);

void doConnect();
void send(QByteArray data);

signals:

public slots:
void connected();
void disconnected();
void bytesWritten(qint64 bytes);
void readyRead();
void quitThread();
private:
QTcpSocket *socket_;
QListWidget *list_;
std::vector<MYThread *> *v_;

MYThread *tt;

void run();

QPixmap *pixmap;
MYThread *socket;

public:
int user_id_;


};

#endif // MYTHREAD_H
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Please format error messages so that they are readable.

Comment: v_ is not a vector, it's a pointer-to-vector. You must dereference it first before trying to access one of it's elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
((MYThread *)(v_)[i])->user_id_
```

tries to convert `v_` to a MYThread* and then perform pointer-math with `i` to find the `i`th element of an array and then derefence that. What you want is

```
v_[i]->user_id_
```

-- Edit --

Based on your clarification of what `v_` is:

```
(*v_)[i]->user_id_
```

http://ideone.com/XxuVjE

Comment: i defined v_    as std::vector<MYThread *> *v_;  in mythread.h file it is list of sockets i can't convert it to MyThread *

Comment: ty but now it give this error : unresolved external symbol "public : ........  i run qmake not fixed i tryed to deleted debug folder but i got same error